# Plotting Distance between Entry and Exit on Strategy

Tags: pine-script

When running a pine strategy, is there a way to plot and display the distance between entry and exit on each trade in points/ticks?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it with [strategy.position_avg_price](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dposition_avg_price) & [syminfo.mintick](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_syminfo%7Bdot%7Dmintick)

and a [label](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_label%7Bdot%7Dnew) to print the value

`pos = ((strategy.position_avg_price - strategy.position_avg_price[1]) / syminfo.mintick) / 10`

l_pos = label.new(bar_index, high, text = tostring(pos))
label.delete(not (strategy.position_avg_price - strategy.position_avg_price[1]) ? l_pos: na)

Comment: Thank you. I added it but am not seeing any values show up on the chart. I tried adding yloc=yloc.abovebar to the label but no cigar. Any ideas?

Comment: For clarity, I'd like the distance between Entry and Exit to be printed above each Exit candle.

Answer (score 0):

With this example:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)


pos = ((strategy.position_avg_price - strategy.position_avg_price[1]) / syminfo.mintick) / 10
l_pos = label.new(bar_index, high, text = tostring(pos))
label.delete(not (strategy.position_avg_price != strategy.position_avg_price[1]) ? l_pos: na)
```

It looks like [this](https://www.tradingview.com/x/OmEw9m4Q/)

Comment: These are my conditions. I wonder if it's not working the same for me because I have a profit and loss exit value set?

Comment: longlovarCondition = (long or blastup and lovar)
if (inDateRange and longlovarCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Exit", loss = 300, profit = 400, trail_points = 200, trail_offset = 300)